# Upgrade PHP 5.2 to 5.3 on SUSE 11.1

Tags: php, sles

i have a client SUSE 11.1 box that now requires PHP 5.3 where as the original scope of work called for PHP 5.2

yast2 doesn't seem to see anything other than 5.2. i can't figure out how to get repositories configured. i really really dislike SUSE and i'm hoping you guys can help. thanks.

Comment: This would be better on serverfault, and you can probably find an answer to this on Google.

Comment: Next to probably the wrong, site, *please* do your homework first.

Comment: sorry guys - yes - you're right - i put it in the wrong forum. my apologies.

as far as research is concerned i've google'd the heck out of this and being a debian guy - i guess i don't know where to start. i simply do not understand the yast system, moreover, why it's hitting the install DVD for software repos rather than the URL i gave it.

Answer (score 1):

zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/php/SLE_11/ php5